# Multiple apps connect to bluetooth issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have 2 applications w/ the bluetooth code derived from the Bluetooth Chat sample.  Individually they work fine.  Each app connects via SPP to separate devices.  The issue I'm having is on phones with Android 2.1, after the first app connects to its device, you can press Home and get to running the other app, but as soon as the connection is made to the other device with this other app, both apps get the "Sorry!  The application xyz (process com.xyz) has stopped unexpectedly.  FORCE CLOSE" dialogs.  There are try/catch blocks throughout the bt code, for which the catches are not executed.  Neither app will then connect (individually) until after bluetooth is turned off then on again.  This does NOT happen when these same apps are running on a Samsung tab with Android 2.2 - both apps can run and connect to the devices simultaneously just fine and you can switch between the apps, no problems.

Is this specifically an Android 2.1 issue or something else?  Whether it is or not, I need some way to prevent the app from connecting if another app is using bluetooth.  I couldn't find anything in the Android APIs that would allow finding this out.  Is there any way to coordinate/manage this?  Does anyone have any specific insights into this whole issue?

Comment: Update: a try/catch block was only looking for IOException, not Exception, so the above unhandled exceptions are now caught.  However, in either case, the following is constantly displayed in the log about once per second:

Comment: 02-02 22:00:04.591 I/BTL_IFC_WRP( 2304): wrp_find_wsock: no entry found
02-02 22:00:04.591 D/BLZ_WRAPPER( 2304): btl_if_poll: wsock down, return POLLHUP poll fd 43, ev 1b
02-02 22:00:04.591 I/BTL_IFC_WRP( 2304): wrp_find_wsock: no entry found
02-02 22:00:04.591 D/BLZ_WRAPPER( 2304): btl_if_poll: wsock down, return POLLHUP poll fd 46, ev 1b
02-02 22:00:05.296 D/dalvikvm( 2681): GC freed 6625 objects / 284648 bytes in 209ms

The GC Freed only happens about every so often, though.

Comment: The above dump only occurs when the phone gets in the condition described above after the 2nd app connects.  In normal operation, this log info does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in the samsung bluetooth stack. 
upgrading the my samsung to cyanogenmod fixes it.

see this link
http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/firmware-problems/connection-problems-sgs-bluetooth-spp-device/